# How to make a URL in JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript

I currently have this JavaScript:

```
new_string = "<p>Problem name: <a href=\"http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=\" + problem_id + ">" + title + "</a></p>";
```

Where the title and problem_id are variables with a string and an id respectively.

How should I approach quotes when I have such situations as I am facing now?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just made a few mistakes with your quotation marks and slashes.  It's best to use both single and double quotes to keep track:

```
new_string = "<p>Problem name: <a href='http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=" + problem_id + "'>" + title + "</a></p>";
```

However, if you'd like to go the slash route:

```
new_string = "<p>Problem name: <a href=\"http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=" + problem_id + "\">" + title + "</a></p>";
```

Comment: Thank you - worked like a charm.  Will accept the answer in 11 min when StackOverflow lets me do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Just end it with a quote:

```
var variable = 0;
var string = "\"quoted\"" + variable + "\"quotes everywhere\""; // "quoted"0"quotes everywhere"
```

Answer (score 2):

`'` for string, `"` for quotes inside string. I'm doing it like this, and I've seen most javascript projects do it that way too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just have one quote out of place:

```
new_string = "<p>Problem name: <a href=\"http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=" + problem_id + "\">" + title + "</a></p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
new_string = "<p>Problem name: <a href=\"http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=" + problem_id + "\">" + title + "</a></p>";
```

Or this:

```
new_string = '<p>Problem name: <a href="http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id='+ problem_id +'">' + title + '</a></p>';
```